# How to create a transaction

Tags: transactions, rpc

I'm trying to understand the different steps involved in the creation of a transaction operation.

`Tezos-client -l` shows a number of RPC calls, among them:

```
chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_operation
chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/operations
injection/operation?chain=main
```

What do `run_operation` and `preapply` do, and why are they both needed?

Besides, the operation to be injected is binary-encoded, what encoding is used? (one can get the encoding using the `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations`, but I'd like encode the operation myself).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple references online which provide material to understand the steps involved in this. You can check [this](https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254) or [that](https://www.ocamlpro.com/2018/11/21/an-introduction-to-tezos-rpcs-signing-operations/). Some elements are also provided in this other [question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/76/how-to-make-an-offline-transaction/89#89)

Basically the steps are

1. get dependencies

   - branch hash: `/chains/main/blocks/head/hash`
   - counter: `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/<source_pkh>/counter`
   - protocol hash: `/protocols`
2. forge operation (`/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations`) Note sure if it's easy to replicate this logic outside from the native client though
3. sign bytes (`tezos-client sign bytes`)
4. preapply operation (`/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/operations/)`
5. decode signature to hexadecimal format
6. inject operation (`/inject/operation`)

Answer (score 4):

`helpers/scripts/run_operation` is useful to simulate an operation without signing it (you may use zero bytes for the signature), in order to estimate the gas and storage requirements. You will see `tezos-client -l` setting gas_limit and storage_limit to the maximum values here, and then using the result to set the actual gas_limit and storage_limit (subject to the user's maximum acceptable storage_limit, called "--burn-cap").

To learn how the operation is encoded in binary, you can see `tezos-client describe unsigned operation`.

Comment: I noticed my answer does not explain why preapply is needed. Why not just run_operation?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be checking out [how e.g. `eztz` implements transfers](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L604).

Then see how the transfer operations is forged [here](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L763).

And finally how the forged operation is injected [here](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L559).

By the looks of it, seems like eztz's `forge` is done remotely by `/helpers/forge/operations`.

Comment: Actually eztz forges locally, but for the time being we use the remote forge as a way to double check that what we forged locally matches. In future, we will remove the remote forge check :-)